# OnClick function not firing when I concat PHP variable as parameter

Tags: php, jquery

I have a jquery function that looks something like this:

```
function removeSectionPhoto(image, section_id) {

    if(confirm("Are you sure you want to remove this image, doing so will also remove it from the Database.") == true) {

        $("#"+$(this).data("remove-row")).remove();
    }
    else{
        alert("Do nothing");
    }
}
```

The function is going to require in parameters, I am outputting an `<a>` from PHP that will include an onClick function.

```
echo "<td><a href='#' class='removeImageRow' data-remove-row='fac_sec_photo_row". $imageRowCount . "' onClick='removeSectionPhoto()'>Remove</a></td>";
```

This works fine while I am not passing any parameters to the function however, when I add in the following parameters like this:

```
echo "<td><a href='#' class='removeImageRow' data-remove-row='fac_sec_photo_row". $imageRowCount . "' onClick='removeSectionPhoto(". $sectionPhotoRow['photo'] .", ". $facilitySecId .")'>Remove</a></td>";
```

It seems to break the function from triggering. I have checked my browser console and after I click the button with added parameters I get a syntax error message

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .

Am I concatenating these parameters wrong, or..?

How can I fix it so that my function will trigger with the added parameters, and without throwing me back a syntax error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add the param in quotes:

```
echo "<td><a href='#' class='removeImageRow' data-remove-row='fac_sec_photo_row". $imageRowCount . "' onClick='removeSectionPhoto(\"". $sectionPhotoRow['photo'] ."\", \"". $facilitySecId ."\")'>Remove</a></td>";
```

Changed content:

```
onClick='removeSectionPhoto(\"". $sectionPhotoRow['photo'] ."\", \"". $facilitySecId ."\")'
```

Comment: This doesn't work because the quotes aren't closing properly.

Comment: Yep, that worked thanks a lot, I will accept the answer as correct when I can (3 minutes). Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this

```
echo "<td><a href='#' class='removeImageRow' data-remove-row='fac_sec_photo_row". $imageRowCount . "' onClick='removeSectionPhoto(\"". $sectionPhotoRow['photo'] ."\", \"". $facilitySecId ."\")'>Remove</a></td>";
```